# Is this search and replace Analytics rule trimming the URL to just root domain?

Tags: regex, filter, google-analytics

In our Google Analytics account I saw this Filter rule setup:

```
SEARCH AND REPLACE the Request URI
Search String:  ^([^\?]+)\?.*
Replace String:  /
```

From what I can tell, with a URL like:

```
example.com/folder/sub-folder?variable=value
```

That Analytics rule is changing it to be literally just:

```
example.com/
```

Is that the proper behavior based on the rule above?

Answer (score 1):

No, you should always, always have a view setup in the account that contains no filters. This way you can see how the data is coming in and this really helps with debugging/identifying issues.

The filter above does exactly what you've mentioned, but you might want to look into WHY before removing it.

Also note, removing it will only affect data from the moment you remove it and forward, it will not affect the past data.

Comment: Thanks! We do have a completely unfiltered view and the problem arose because we were seeing pages with parameters in the URL in that unfiltered view, but NOT in the view that has that filter above.  There are many filters but this appears to be the culprit.  I still don't see the page with parameters in the URL showing in the "site content" report, but it does show in the Real-Time view when I test, so I assume there's some sort of delay happening with the non-RealTime reports.

Comment: If you go into Admin in GA, under "View Settings" there's the field for "Exclude URL Query Parameters", check to see if anything's filled in there.